# BibTex error after trying Chicago style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, texshop

I tried Chicago style citations by using the instructions available here (https://www.reed.edu/it/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html)

So I passed to the biber engine, entered the commands indicated. However, it did not work, so in the meantime I returned to the usual bibtex engine, and to the usual commands I had before and that worked just fine.

The problem is: now when I try to compile in bibtex it does not work* and the compiler (Texshop) stops functioning (I have to arrest it). What is the problem here?

If you need additional information, let me know.

Thank you.

- It means: I want to do the usual sequence Latex->Bibtex->Latex->Latex. So I compile in Latex and it works, then I Typeset in Bibtex, the console opens but it remains empty (if I wait nothing happens), I close the console and try hitting the typeset button. Nothing happens. TexShop stop working.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (even if I think it's a TeXShop problem, and I can't help with it): https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography?rq=1. Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Dear @CarLaTeX, it is a problem of TeXShop for sure. I was able to circumvent the inconvenience by typesetting in pdflatexmk, XeLateX and finally LateX and the document produced does not suffer any problem. How to clear the cache?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to clear the cache with TeXShop, in other editors there is an option like "Remove auxiliary files". You may try to cancel them manually (delete the `.aux`, `.bcf`, etc. of your document, paying attention NOT to remove the `.tex` and `.bib`).